# How to change 1 digit in multiple cells at the same time?

Tags: excel

I have a list of 64 product codes all similar to `SDAC30610`.

I have also had to append 2 digits on to the end of each cell, and have done that using `=sourceA2&"PA"`, but cannot figure out how to change an existing digit in each cell.

**How do I change the `3` to a `4` in all 64 cells?**

Answer (score 1):

Can't you try just find and replace all?

```
Find "SDAC3" and replace with "SDAC4"
```

Or use replace function, see https://www.exceltip.com/working-with-formulas/replace-a-particular-character-at-specific-position.html

Something like this should work:

```
=IF((MID(A2,5,1))=”3”,REPLACE(A2,5,1,4),A2)
```

Then you should be able copy that for all rows in that column.

Comment: All the codes are the same length and contain `3` as the 5th character, but the codes are all different, they do not all start `SDAC`

Comment: never knew about `REPLACE` as I always have used `SUBSTITUTE`.  You made me look up the difference.  Thank you.

Comment: If this is accepted answer can you check it?  Thanks and glad it helped.